# How to remove the effect of light / shadow on my model in XNA?

Tags: graphics, model, 3d, xna, game-engine

I am developing a small game and I would draw a field-ground(land) with a repeated texture. My problem is the rendered result. This gives the impression of seeing everything around my cube looked as if a light shadow.
Is it possible to standardize the light or remove the shadow effect in my drawing function?

Sorry for my bad english..

Here is a screenshot to better understand my problem.
[image]

Here my code draw function (instancing model with vertexbuffer)

```
    // Draw Function (instancing model - vertexbuffer)
    public void DrawModelHardwareInstancing(Model model,Texture2D texture, Matrix[] modelBones,
                                     Matrix[] instances, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
    {
        if (instances.Length == 0)
            return;

        // If we have more instances than room in our vertex buffer, grow it to the neccessary size.
        if ((instanceVertexBuffer == null) ||
            (instances.Length > instanceVertexBuffer.VertexCount))
        {
            if (instanceVertexBuffer != null)
                instanceVertexBuffer.Dispose();

            instanceVertexBuffer = new DynamicVertexBuffer(Game.GraphicsDevice, instanceVertexDeclaration,
                                                           instances.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        }

        // Transfer the latest instance transform matrices into the instanceVertexBuffer.
        instanceVertexBuffer.SetData(instances, 0, instances.Length, SetDataOptions.Discard);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in mesh.MeshParts)
            {
                // Tell the GPU to read from both the model vertex buffer plus our instanceVertexBuffer.
                Game.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffers(
                    new VertexBufferBinding(meshPart.VertexBuffer, meshPart.VertexOffset, 0),
                    new VertexBufferBinding(instanceVertexBuffer, 0, 1)
                );

                Game.GraphicsDevice.Indices = meshPart.IndexBuffer;


                // Set up the instance rendering effect.
                Effect effect = meshPart.Effect;
                //effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["HardwareInstancing"];
                effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(modelBones[mesh.ParentBone.Index]);
                effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(view);
                effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(projection);
                effect.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(texture);


                // Draw all the instance copies in a single call.
                foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
                {
                    pass.Apply();

                    Game.GraphicsDevice.DrawInstancedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0,
                                                           meshPart.NumVertices, meshPart.StartIndex,
                                                           meshPart.PrimitiveCount, instances.Length);
                }
            }



        }
    }
    // ### END FUNCTION DrawModelHardwareInstancing
```

Comment: Do you know if it's a lighting problem or a texture problem?

Comment: What program are you using to design the models?

Comment: I use Blender and yes i'm sur , Is not a texture problem

Comment: By default normals in Blender are not averaged. I encourage you to play with the normals to try to fix the model. Does the Render view show flat faces or shaded faces? If the faces in the Render view are flat, the problem is probably with the export.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the cube mesh you are using. The normals are averaged, but I guess you want them to be orthogonal to the faces of the cubes.

You will have to use a total of 24 vertices (4 for each side) instead of 8 vertices. Each corner will have 3 vertices with the same position but different normals, one for each adjacent face:

[image: two cubes, one with shared normals, one with correct normals]

If the FBX exporter cannot be configured to correctly export the normals simply create your own cube mesh:

```
var vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[24];

// Initialize the vertices, set position and texture coordinates
// ...

// Set normals

// front face
vertices[0].Normal = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
vertices[1].Normal = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
vertices[2].Normal = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
vertices[3].Normal = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

// back face
vertices[4].Normal = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
vertices[5].Normal = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
vertices[6].Normal = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
vertices[7].Normal = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got improperly calculated / no normals.
[Look at this example, specifically part 3.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464051%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx)

A normal is a vector that describes the direction that light would reflect off that vertex/poly if shined orthogonally to it.

[I like this picture to demonstrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSurface_normal.png) The blue lines are the normal direction at each particular point on the curve.

In XNA, you can calculate the normal of a polygon with vertices vert1,vert2,and vert3 like so:

```
Vector3 dir = Vector3.Cross(vert2 - vert1, vert3 - vert1);
Vector3 norm = Vector3.Normalize(dir);
```

In a lot of cases this is done automatically by modelling software so the calculation is unnecessary.  You probably do need to perform that calculation if you're creating your cubes in code though.

Comment: Ah ok! I use Blender to generate a model ('fbx') and after I load this model in my XNA project. This means that I can change the light effect in my code or in my Blender project ?

Comment: Could give it a try. Those are some pretty strange normals for even blender. Sometimes it averages normals of shared edges when it really should be having orthogonal normals. Try selecting your whole cube in blender and hitting P. This will separate all the faces and it should give you more sane normals.

Comment: Another thought, it might be doing that because of the FBX exporter -- however it does triangulation. If the above doesn't work, try triangulating the cube in blender, select all in edit mode, then ( CTRL+T ), then split: ( P )

Comment: This removes my UV mapping